# CRM 2011 Ribbon DisplayRule ValueRule not working

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I am currently trying to show/hide a custom ribbon button based on the value of a checkbox on the form.

I have managed to get my XML working fine with the `<EnableRule>` i created but once i try using a `<DisplayRule>`, the button in question disappears regardless of whatever value i put into the `new_is_trading` field.

Here is my XML below:

```
        <CommandUIDefinition>
          <Group Id="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomGroup.Group" 
                 Command="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomGroup.Command" 
                 Title="Client Commands" 
                 Sequence="51" 
                 Template="Mscrm.Templates.Flexible2">

              <Controls Id="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomGroup.Controls">
              <Button Id="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomGroup.Button.A" 
                      Command="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomGroup.Button.A.Command"
                      Sequence="10" 
                      LabelText="Custom Button" 
                      ToolTipTitle="Description" 
                      ToolTipDescription="Should only be shown if this account is trading" 
                      TemplateAlias="o1" 
                      Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/CustomEntity_16.png" 
                      Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/CustomEntity_32.png" />
            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
```

Then in my rule definitions:

```
    <RuleDefinitions>
      <TabDisplayRules />
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomDisplayRules.DisplayIfClient">
          <ValueRule Field="new_is_trading" Value="true" />
        </DisplayRule>
      </DisplayRules>
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Form.account.CustomEnableRules.EnableIfClient">
          <ValueRule Field="new_is_trading" Value="true" />
        </EnableRule>
      </EnableRules>
    </RuleDefinitions>
```

Again, my `EnableRule` works fine but my `DisplayRule` does not for some reason!

Comment: Are you sure Display Rule checks are fired after the page has loaded for the first time? I was under the impression Display Rules were only for page load and after that you could simply enable/disable them.

Comment: I have tried opening records wherte the value has been both true and false but in neither case would the button show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 1(true) and 0(false) to compare Boolean values - this will work.
I've the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you're enable is working but here is an example of a working command definition I'm using.  This doesn't use the value attribute, but I know the code below works fine and it appears you're missing a reference to the rules you created...

```
    <CommandDefinitions>
      <CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.Isv.account.grid.ShowMap.Command">
        <EnableRules>
          <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Isv.account.Clients.EnableRule" />
          <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.Isv.account.grid.OneSelected.EnableRule" />
        </EnableRules>
        <DisplayRules>
          <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.Isv.account.Clients.DisplayRule" />
        </DisplayRules>
        <Actions>
          <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:way_showBingMapAll.js" FunctionName="showBingMap" />
        </Actions>
      </CommandDefinition>
    </CommandDefinitions>
```

Comment: You're listing the command definitions, which simply provides references to `EnableRule`s and `DisplayRule`s defined in the `RuleDefinitions` section he's describing.